# How do I insert dynamic dates passed into a sql query using a python function?

Tags: python, string

I have a function that queries google cloud platform through a jupyter notebook.  How do I change the function to allow for dynamic date entry?

See below an example:
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

```
def get_data(start, end):
    start_ = start
    end_ = end
    client = bigquery.Client(location="US")

    query = """
    select date, sales 
    from data_table 
    where date between start_ and end_
    """
 query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location="US",
    )  # API request - starts the query

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

I tried the following:

```
def get_data(start, end):
start_ = start
end_ = end
client = bigquery.Client(location="US")

query = """
select date, sales 
from data_table 
where date between {} and {}
""".format(start_, end_)
 query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location="US",
    )  # API request - starts the query

df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

But that didn't recognize it and I got the following:

````
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12962/4209258901.py in <module>
----> 1 df_test = get_data_test.test_data(start = 202201, end = 202204)

~/get_data_test.py in test_data(start, end)
    174         )  # API request - starts the query
    175 
--> 176     df = query_job.to_dataframe()
    177     print("data pulled....changing types")
    178 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py in to_dataframe(self, bqstorage_client, dtypes, progress_bar_type, create_bqstorage_client, date_as_object, max_results, geography_as_object)
   1692                 :mod:`shapely` library cannot be imported.
   1693         """
-> 1694         query_result = wait_for_query(self, progress_bar_type, max_results=max_results)
   1695         return query_result.to_dataframe(
   1696             bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_tqdm_helpers.py in wait_for_query(query_job, progress_bar_type, max_results)
     86     )
     87     if progress_bar is None:
---> 88         return query_job.result(max_results=max_results)
     89 
     90     i = 0

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py in result(self, page_size, max_results, retry, timeout, start_index, job_retry)
   1496                 do_get_result = job_retry(do_get_result)
   1497 
-> 1498             do_get_result()
   1499 
   1500         except exceptions.GoogleAPICallError as exc:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    286                 sleep_generator,
    287                 self._deadline,
--> 288                 on_error=on_error,
    289             )
    290 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline, on_error)
    188     for sleep in sleep_generator:
    189         try:
--> 190             return target()
    191 
    192         # pylint: disable=broad-except

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py in do_get_result()
   1486                     self._job_retry = job_retry
   1487 
-> 1488                 super(QueryJob, self).result(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
   1489 
   1490                 # Since the job could already be "done" (e.g. got a finished job

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py in result(self, retry, timeout)
    726 
    727         kwargs = {} if retry is DEFAULT_RETRY else {"retry": retry}
--> 728         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
    729 
    730     def cancelled(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout, retry)
    135             # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    136             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 137             raise self._exception
    138 
    139         return self._result

BadRequest: 400 Unrecognized name: start_ at [137:40]

Location: US
Job ID: 4a43e5b8-47cc-4d30-a5f2-df55f427ae65```

I feel like this is a simple fix and I'm just missing it.
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.  I just changed the following and added the following line:

```
where date between {start_date} and {end_date}

query = query.format(start_date = start_, end_date = end_)
```